# Размытие по гауссу.

Tags: графика, фильтры

Вот у меня вопрос: почему в основе фильтра лежит [гауссиана](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)? Нельзя ли обойтись обычной параболой? По сути же графики одинаковые?

Comment: я бы не сказал, что гауссовое распределение и парабола одинаковые.

Comment: Потому, что фильтр Гаусса. Очевидно же.

Comment: @KoVadim, Хм, на вид одинаковые, если подобрать подходящие коэффициенты

Comment: в небольшом диапазоне да. Но в очень небольшом. Но можете попробовать подобрать, посмотрим.

Answer (score 4):

Гауссова функция стремится к нуля при модуле аргумента, стремящемуся к бесконечности; её интеграл по всей плоскости конечен. Это значит, что фильтр на её основе можно *нормировать*: сделать так, чтобы среднее значение фильтруемых данных не изменилось (то есть фильтр будет как бы размазывать данные, не добавляя новых).

Парабола же (перевёрнутая) стремится к минус бесконечности, так что она никак не подходит. К тому же интеграл от неё расходится, так что после фильтрации вы с хорошими шансами получите бесконечно большие значения -- и какой их смысл?

---

У гауссовой функции особое значение, обусловленное [ЦПТ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0) (случайные величины имеют тенденцию быть распределёнными по Гауссу), но это оффтопик для нашего форума.

Comment: @VladD,

1.(стремится к нулю...) Я же не собираюсь рассчитывать матрицу свёртки с бесконечными размерами. Я могу подобрать коэффициент a (y=-ax^2) так, чтобы элемент n>0 (одномерная матрица свёртки размером n).

2. Чтобы нормировать фильтр, можно значение, полученное после свёртки, разделить на сумму коэффициентов матрицы свёртки.

http://habrahabr.ru/post/142818/

Comment: @ололо: то есть вы фактически собираетесь делать свёртку с функцией f(x) = a - bx^2 при |x| <= x0; f(x) = 0 при |x| > x0. Тогда ваша функция свёртки будет негладкая в окрестности x0, то есть свойства точек на отдалении > x0 будут скачкообразно влиять по-другому. Это не есть гут. С гауссовой функцией такого не будет.